# API Gateway - Custom Lambda Authorizer, Validate passed header value (username) exists in Cognito User pool group

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to make a custom authorizer in API Gateway that uses a lambda function to check if the user's email (passed in their request) to us, is a valid email (being valid, I mean a user that we have in our Cognito user pool/group) and is in a specific Cognito user pool, and then the specific Cognito user group that they are in.

I see that there are two different types of Lambda Authorizers that I can make, either ***Token*** or ***Request***, I sort of think either are valid uses for this?
Because in the end I need to be able to specify the header the client is going to send and check that key's value to see if the username passed is in Cogntio.

Example,

```
User tries to query endpoint petstore.com/getDogs
user passes header: username: test@gmail.com
```

API Gateway custom lambda auth checks the header `username`, gets the value `test@gmail.com` and then verifies that it does or doesn't exist in a specific Cognito user pool/group.

Comment: U just want to validate email format in lambda or have other logic which you want  to implement ?

Comment: Other logic, like if they are in a very specific cognito group.

Example, 
User sends a request to view a list of dogs, but I don't want them to see that if they aren't in the cognito group "dogwatchers"